# IIS Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS including Application Name

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm adding a URL redirect rule to redirect a user from HTTP to HTTPS in a way that it preserves the original query. For example...

http://localhost/myapp/test >> 
https://localhost/myapp/test

http://localhost/myapp/test?id=test >> 
https://localhost/myapp/test?id=test

However the application name isn't being included in the redirect so what I actually get is the following...

http://localhost/myapp/test >>
https://localhost/test

**Inbound Rule**

[image: inbound rules]

**IIS structure**

- Sites

  - Default Web site

    - MyApp

I believe I'm missing a IIS variable in my redirect url https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1} which represents the application.

Is there a IIS variable that represents the application level(MyApp) I can add to the redirect URL, or another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by adding the URL variable.

```
https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}
```